# Power Query: Azure Management API (pagination &automatic refresh)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In order to avoid a dynamic url in Web.Contents (to automatically refresh dashboard in Power BI Services), and given tha paging system of the Azure API, I wrote the code below to achieve so, but I found out that in the HTTP request, the Path variable in query_param is url-encoded, making it different to the URL expected by the API.

Is there any way to disable this encoding or do you know another approach to change the parameters of the URL properly?

Thank you in advance.

```
let
        GetPages = (Path as text)=>
        let
            Host = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2022-11-01",
            query_param= [#"api-version"=Path],

            Source = Json.Document(
                Web.Contents(
                    Host, 
                    [Query = query_param]
                )),
            LL= @Source[value],
 
            Next = Text.Replace(Source[#"nextLink"], Host, ""),
            result = try @LL & @GetPages(Next) otherwise @LL
        in
        result,

        Host = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines?api-version=2022-11-01",
        Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(Host)),
        Next = Text.Replace(Source[#"nextLink"], Host, ""),
        first= @Source[value],
        Fullset = first&GetPages(Next)

in Fullset
```

I have tried Query and RelativePath parameters of Web.Contents, but I need to keep the Host variable fixed in order to sign in via Power BI Services and apply automatic refresh. Correct me if I am wrong, please!